# jquery change class if attribute value =

Tags: jquery

Good Morning,

Sorry i think its a simple "stupid" question but i have a big blank.

I want to change a class if the attr value is equal to a given value.

**I have the following:**

```
 <a str=10 href="start.php class="old">Start<a>
```

So if str attr from a is 10 i will set the class to class="new"

**I have tried somethig like:**

```
$('a.attr.subnr.10).addClass('old');
```

I think its to early in the morning :-(

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this simple statement:

```
$("a[str='10']").addClass("old");
```

Comment: Thank you its the simplest way !

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `str` is not a valid attribute, consider using `data-str`

You can do it like

```
if($('a').attr('data-str') == 10) {
    $('a').addClass('add_class');
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TTgTW/)

---

Make sure you use a specific selector, this is a generalized one, so consider using something like `.parent a`

---

If you want a pure CSS solution, than you can also use `attr=value` selector like

```
a[data-str="10"] {
   color: red;
}
```

This won't add a class to your element, but you can target it using the above selector.

Comment: Thank you for this good expression ! You are right str is not a valid value but in my case sad to say necessary :-(

Comment: @Phantom001 use the quotes around the value atleast..

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[str=10]').removeClass('old').addClass('new');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('a[str=10]').removeClass('oldClass').addClass('newClass');
$('a[str!=10]').removeClass('newClass').addClass('OldClass');
```